# livepatch (Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error)

Tags: canonical-livepatch

my livepatch has a red sign it says Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error. Please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues for further information.

i've tried to refresh, also simple restart and new token nothing have worked. thank you

the logs:

```
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: Client.Check
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: Module may have caused kernel crash! Not inserting module.
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: To override this warning, remove /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_42_46_generic_70_70.3
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: during refresh: multiple failures
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: during refresh: cannot check: apply-failed
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: during refresh: cannot apply patches: lock file "/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_42_46_generic_70_70.3" already exists
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: failure when getting status: apply-failed
Aug 28 23:21:38 rmu-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB canonical-livepatch[912]: failure getting status after refresh: apply-failed
```

Comment: Did you "rremove /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_42_46_generic_70_70.3"?

Comment: Thank you for response, yes i have deleted the file that has red color, using sudo rm ......, then used refresh, but that didn't work. I have deleted Ubuntu and install it again but the same problem appear i am near madness please help

Comment: Go to the Livepatch settings panel, and turn off/sign out, then sign back in again and turn on Livepatch.

Comment: unfortunately didn't work. I appreciate your work but i think problem will last forever

Answer (score 1):

I am new to ubuntu 20.04 just a few days old and I encountered the same problem.

Here is a quick fix that worked for me. Fire up terminal and run

```
sudo canonical-livepatch refresh
```